# CCSprite has weird white pixels around the border

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm facing a weird problem in cocos2d for my iPhone game. I have created a PNG file as below

[image: MyBalls.png 64x64 pixels]

In cocos2d, I use CCSpriteSheet to get each ball all of the with PNG file. It works well until then.

However, the weird thing is that on the iPhone's screen, the ball has weird white pixels around the border, as shown in the below screenshot

[image]

I have done so many researches on the web. But every suggestion like using TexturePacker or reset the glBlendFunc didn't work :(

Do you have any idea?

**Update: I try to used normal CCSprite with separate PNG file of only one ball, the problem is still! I guess that I have to configure the cocos2d sourcecode some how to get it worked.**

Comment: I can propose that your image has artifacts in alpha channel (especially if it has premultiplied alpha). Does it look nice in image editor? Try to blur image and look for artifacts. And at last, what exactly are blending values?

Comment: actually, I'm not a graphic designer, I'm a iOS developer. And my image is displayed perfectly in Photoshop, even when I zoom to 1600% without a single white pixels. I think I will use a special software to render images for iOS game TexturePacker to the automation :(

Comment: What pixel format are you using? Try 8888.

Comment: yes, I'm using 8888. I have contacted the developer of TexturePacker and he confirmed that my problem will be solved with this tool :)

Comment: perhaps try in gimp or photoshop to set the background to black. Do you see the contour artifact? if yes, this is simply a problem with your asset, and you will need to remove white pixels in your favorite art program.

Comment: the image is simply perfect in Photoshop (with whatever background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. Not because of the graphic itself. It's because of the box2d create an outline for the b2Fixture on the back of the CCSprite. Here I posted a question for that specific question!

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/25368?replies=1#post-132008